# Vague Assignment with possible pointer function

Tags: c++

This a class assignment in which I have to figure out what's going on in the program without much details and just make it work.  It looks the function may be intended to use a pointer type int in the prototype but then it doesn't have a * in the definition.  I have the freedom to change the code as needed but I'm supposed to keep the function.  Any tips?

```
// Question4
//
// This question has no instructions, simply make it work properly.
// (Ask for a number and print it out.) Keep the function.
//

#include <iostream>

void MyFunc( int * ) ;

int main()
{
int i = 0;
cout << “Enter an integer: " << endl;
cout << "The value entered is: " << MyFunc(i) << endl;
}

void MyFunc( int x )
{
cin >> x ;
cout << "\n\n\n";
return x;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a home work

Comment: It looks like the program has deliberate errors and your job is to identify and fix them. You correctly identified a discrepancy between the prototype and its definition. Now what needs to be done to make it correct?

Comment: Note to down voters, homework questions are welcome on Stack Overflow. Just don't answer them outright. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811

Comment: I suspect the question is more than just fixing the formal errors, but also the flawed thinking. Hint: look at that parameter of `MyFunc` again. If you would write the documentation for the function, how would you document the parameter?

Answer (score -1):

Either:

- make the function return an int
- make the function return something that prints like an int (a little trickier, for testing your teacher)
- make the parameter an int reference and return the reference

Comment: It never specifies that the int itself must be the return value, why not just return a void pointer and see what happens?

Comment: Well, “keep the function” does not exactly mean “call the function”. So that would be another variant: just write everything in the `main` function. I thought the main function should have been left as-is, but this was of course my self-restriction.